# How to show a map with queries from a map file connected to postgres in browser using javascript?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, geowebcache, mapfile, spatial-query

So, the problem is how to show a map in browser using JavaScript.

I have a map file with 2 layers in it: "peta" is a `shp` data from PostGIS and "korban" is a numeric data from PostgreSQL, and then I have a HTML file, in that file I use JavaScript to show a toolbar but I don't know how to show the map from map files.

I have tried to call map file with "http://my.site/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/webgis.map&LAYERS=all&MODE=MAP" and the map shows but it cannot be zoomed, so I need to know how to show map with a query?

The query I mean is something like this

```
var query = 'select ' + 'admin_90_des(edit_pande,jawa)_2010."gid", ' + 'data_korban."2009", ' + 'admin_90_des(edit_pande,jawa)_2010."kel_desa", ' +
'admin_90_des(edit_pande,jawa)_2010."kecamatan", ' + 'admin_90_des(edit_pande,jawa)_2010."geom"' +
'FROM "admin_90_des(edit_pande,jawa)_2010" ' + '"data_korban"' +
'where "admin_90_des(edit_pande,jawa)_2010".gid="data_korban".gid ';

new_dbd = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Peta", "http://my.site/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/webgis/webgis02.map&LAYERS=ALL&MODE=MAP&korbanDBD=geom FROM (" +
query +
") AS foo USING UNIQUE gid and USING SRID=-1", {
    layers: ['korban', 'peta'],
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true
}, {
    isBaseLayer: false
});

map.addLayers([new_dbd]);
```

But I don't understand how it works so please anyone can explain to me or at least give me some clue how can I show my map in browser?

Comment: One problem you have is the `mode=map` parameter.  When you use this you don't get a WMS response and you have the problem you describe, ie a non zoomable map. Just remove the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't do what you're trying to do. OpenLayers requires that you pass in a URL to a WMS endpoint e.g.

> http://my.host.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=mywms.map&

In your example above you are pointing to a MapServer map, not a WMS endpoint. The next problem is that I don't think MapServer allows you to filter or query WMS requests.

GeoServer has CQL support that does exactly this:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#cql-filter

If there isn't a requirement to self host the map I would just use CartoDB, it can do exactly what you want [out of the box](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html). Who says that I only ever plug [Mango](https://mangomap.com) on here? ;-)